# How to import Django settings in a celery task?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Since [version 3.1 of celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#django-supported-out-of-the-box), there's not need to install *django-celery* because is already included. I read something about [Accept settings on the command line](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) but I'm not sure if that's the better way. I also have the settings as a module, so for instance I would need to import *my_project.settings.dev*.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Celery tasks are usually part of your app. Why can't you just do `from django.conf import settings` like you would anywhere else?

Comment: yup, that did the work but you need to do `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings.dev')` in your celery.py file. Thanks!